# SocketIO GET MAC OSX timeout

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I have an Angular Socket.IO application that works well on my windows machine (Chrome and Firefox)
When I cloned the repo onto my mac and started up the application, the app seems to be hanging and never loads and the browser times out. After trying to figure it out, I realized it has to do with the Socket IO. I am not sure why it works well on windows but not mac.

Here is a screenshot of what the dev console looks like.
[image: Here is what the dev console looks like in Safari. This just seems to be loading forever]

I am not sure what other files would be useful for anyone to see, so I can post other scripts at your request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a function in an HTML attribute that was being called repeatedly. It was overloading the browser, causing the freeze